# Matlab - Path to Function File calling a Function File

Tags: matlab, path

I have a function `f0.m` (the target, any function, not allowed to be modified) which calls a function `f1.m` (the command).

Inside `f1.m` I am needing to know the path of the caller function `f0.m`.

`mfilename('fullpath')` and `S=dbstack('-completenames'); S(1).file` gives the current file `f1.m` and `matlab.desktop.editor.getActiveFilename` gives the Active file in the editor (whatever it is).

What must I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mfilename` or `dbstack` inside `f0` to get the path of `f0.m`. Pass the path of `f0` as an input argument to `f1`.

```
function out_f0 = f0(inp_f0)
%whatever you have in here
f0path = mfilename('fullpath');
out_f1 = f1(inp_f1, f0path);
%...
end
```

```
function out_f1 = f1(inp_f1, f0path)
%whatever you have in here
end
```